# Ionic pierde estilos al compilar a producción

Tags: android, ionic, ionic-framework, aplicación-movil

Hola compañer@s tengo un problema y es el siguiente cuando compilo una aplicación con el comando Ionic Cordova Build Android --prod --release compila sin error, firmo la app y cuando le ejecuto en el dispositivo físico la primera vez que se abre carga todos los estilos pero después que se abre la segunda vez pierde gran parte de los estilos en toda la app, la cuestión es que no pasa en iOS y solo pasa en Android cuando se genera el release pero si se compila en debug no pasa eso.
Alguien le ha pasado eso o tiene alguna idea de que puede ser, gracias.

Comment: Que version de cordova android tienes instalada?

Comment: Actualizando @ionic/app-scripts  a  3.0.0 creo que podria ayudarte.